# Wamp Server : Path of uploaded files

Tags: path, wamp

Hi I have a WAMP server where some files are upload into an specific path.

> C:\wamp\www\upload\

in this case. However could it be possible to upload these files into for example

> D:\Documents\User\upload ?

`Upload.php` specifies the path where the files are stored but I haven´t the way of changing to another path.

Thanks in advance,
Katherine

Edit: upload.php

Here is the upload_file.php

```
<?php
$target_path  = "c:\\";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "El fichero ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." ha sido enviado";
} else{
 echo "Hubo un error, inténtalo de nuevo!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You say the path is in upload.php but you can't change it? Why not? Can we see the code?

Comment: Hi sarah thank you for ansewring. I upload the file correctly in path ./ but if I chnag to C:\ for example it does not work

Comment: Apache likely doesn't have permissions to write to C:\ root (and it shouldn't). How is the script failing? Do you get a permissions error? Does it just not upload? Look in your PHP error log if no errors appear on the page. You may want to switch the permissions on whichever folder you attempt to upload to to 777 while you are figuring this out.

Comment: Hi Sarah thanks again, it just dont upload the file in that server. Im a bit lost, how could I chnage the permissions for example in order to write in D:

Comment: You should be able to right click on the folder you want the script to be able to write to and choose Security and then give 'Everyone' read and write permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Katherine,

In WAMP, Apache is setup ( as it should be for security reasons ) so that Apache will not allow access to the root folder of the C:\

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    **Deny from all**
</Directory>
```

This stops hackers that successfully break into your site from being allowed to cause **REALLY SERIOUS DAMAGE.**

So I would expect to see an error message in either your Apache error log or your Php error log. I would also expect to see and error on the screen from XDEBUG unless you have disabled that feature. Maybe you should re-enable it as these error messages are really useful while you are developing!!!

change php.ini
display_errors = On

Now it is possible to open up specific folders outside the normal website folder structure like this

```
This is an excerpt from the httpd.ini without all the comments
<Directory "d:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

    </Directory>
    Alias /my_other_upload_folder_alias "c:/some_other/folder/my_other_upload_folder"
    <Directory "c:/some_other/folder/my_other_upload_folder">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

You then use 'my_other_upload_folder_alias' as the folder name in your php code.

PS. You look like you are placing your site into c:\wamp\www  this is a bad idea!
Create subfolders for your sites like this

```
c:\wamp\www\site1  
c:\wamp\www\site2
```

And think about create one virtualHost per site.

Comment: Thank you for the piece of advise